# NSCollectionView Window Changes Window Size Depending On Whether You Quit Program Or Stop from Xcode

Tags: xcode4, nscollectionview

If I stop the program from Xcode the window uses the last size I had after resizing the window. If I quit the program while it is running, it resets to the size specified in the Width and Height values for the View which contains the collection view. I'm using a nib for the collection view. I don't understand why this is happening and I don't know how to get the current view size for the collection view. It always gives me the IB sizes for the enclosing view no matter what size the actual window is.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, I think. isIntialController in the collection view scene in IB needs to be checked for the window size to work.